# Viewbag is null in alert

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

i wrote behind code.
but Viewbag.message will show null in alert message .myvar  is a variable.
i used breakpoint , myvar   will set by Viewbag.message correctly. but it will be shown null in alert .

```
         <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
         <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

   @{string myvar = ViewBag.AlertMessage;}

   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("action", "controller", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post",    OnSuccess = "Messsage" }))
                   {

  <script type="text/javascript">

   function Messsage() {

    alert('@ViewBag.AlertMessage');    //infact, it shows alert('');
    }


  </script>
```

Comment: I would assume the Ajax call from the BeginForm is clearing the ViewBag for this particular view or having it inside of the form tag could also be clearing its values.  What happens if you call alert("@myvar"); instead?  Also, try moving the JavaScript outside of the Ajax.BeginForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Messsage() {
    alert('@myvar');    // should show "hello there"
}
</script>
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AjaxAction", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "Messsage" }))
{

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Messsage() {

            alert("@ViewBag.AjaxMessage");
        }
    </script>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

}
```

Answer (score 0):

is the `ViewBag.AlertMessage` being defined in the controller action ?

you can replace the data by

```
@{string myvar = "hello there !";}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Messsage() {
        alert('@myvar');    // should show "hello there"
    }
</script>
```

or define your viewbag item in the action method behind the result

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    ViewBag.AlertMessage = "hello there !"
    return View();
}
```

Comment: yes i defined in controller . ViewBag.AlertMessage should pass from controller. because it will change Continuously.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the value for ViewBag.AlertMessage in controller action  that returns the view on which you have defined the Ajax.Begin form.

eg

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";
            ViewBag.AlertMessage = "AjaxMessage.";

            return View();
        }
     }
```

on Index view  i have placed the following code, calling AjaxAction on Home Controller.

```
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AjaxAction", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "Messsage" }))
    {

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Messsage() {

                alert("@ViewBag.AjaxMessage");
            }
        </script>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    }
```